# Intermittent issues in xslt transformer template when using a splitter with an executor channel

Tags: java, spring, xslt, spring-integration

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156273/handling-exceptions-inside-of-multithreaded-splitter-aggregator-orchestration-to/60156691#60156691) question yesterday, which Gary solved. This fixed the error handling problem (which I will need), but it made me uncover that I am having an intermittent issue on the xslt transformer where I am getting an exception evaluating the template at a specific line.  And that line in the template is the base match.

Interestingly this error only occurs sometimes, often the orchestration will complete and I will receive the response that I was expecting, but other times it seems that one of the executor channel threads will have a runtime exception on that xslt transformer template match. I believe that something wonky is happening to my message in the failure situations but have failed to uncover why this is occurring intermittently.

I hate asking questions so frequently, but I'm at a complete standstill on this issue and would appreciate any feedback you spring integration gurus can provide.

The error message that I receive is the following:

```
failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: error occurred in message handler, nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error evaluating template on line X
```

Where the template on that line is found below.

`xslt`

```xml
<xsl:template match="/">
   <request>
    ...
   </request>
</xsl:template>
```

`context`

```xml
<bean id="Splitter" class="com.MessageSplitter">
   <property name="splitFieldName" value="boundIndexList" />
</bean>

<bean id="Aggregator" class="com.MessageAggregator">
   <property name="wrapperNode" value="container" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="splitter_input" />
<int:channel id="splitter_output">
   <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="4"/>
<int:channel id="aggregator_input" />

<int:splitter id="splitter" input-channel="splitter_input" output-channel="splitter_output"
      ref="Splitter" method="splitHeaderParamByFieldName" />

<int:chain input-channel="splitter_output" output-channel="aggregator_input">
   <!-- ***RuntimeException thrown here sometimes*** -->
   <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-templates="XsltTemplate">
      <int-xml:xslt-param name="customHeader" expression="headers.boundIndexList" />
   </int-xml:xslt-transformer>

   <int:gateway request-channel="outbound_gateway" error-channel="exception_errorChannel" />

</int:chain>

<bean id="messageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />


<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregator_input" output-channel="aggregator_output" 
     ref="Aggregator" method="aggregateMessages" send-partial-result-on-expiry="false" 
     expire-groups-upon-completion="true" message-store="viewResRemoveMessageFromStore" />
```

`splitter`

```java
public List<Message<String>> splitHeaderParamByFieldName(Message<String> message) throws XPathExpressionException {

   List<Message<String>> result = new ArrayList<Message<String>>();

   Object paramValue = message.getHeaders().get(splitFieldName);

   if (paramValue instanceof List<?>) {
      for (Object value : (List<?>) paramValue) {
         Message<String> newMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                  .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                  .setHeader("customHeader", value)
                  .setHeader("receiveTimeout", 60000)
                  .build();
         result.add(newMessage);

      }
   } else {
      result.add(message);
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: I think it is thrown because not all your messages have a nominated header `<int-xml:xslt-param name="customHeader" expression="headers.boundIndexList" />`. Please, consider to show more stack trace or even better share with us some simple project, so we can run it locally and reproduce. Although it doesn't sound like issue related to Spring Integration: `Internal error evaluating template` means clear XSLT, so can be reproduces even without Spring Integration...

Comment: Thanks artem, can always count on you, I will investigate and update the question accordingly

Comment: Since the XSLT processor is reporting an internal error, we really need to know which XSLT processor you're using. The message "Internal error evaluating template on line" is very similar to a Saxon message, but not quite. Perhaps it's an old release, or perhaps you paraphrased the message? Getting a stack trace would also be really useful. One thing to look for is that you aren't trying to use the same Transformer object in multiple threads.

Comment: @Michael Kay I am trying to use the same XSLT template for all of the threads that spawn, is there a way that I can have an individual transformer for each thread? Unfortunately, that is the whole error message that I have in my logs.

Comment: If you're using the JAXP interface, then the Templates object represents the compiled stylesheet and this can be used concurrently in multiple threads. The Transformer object represents an individual transformation, and this can only be used in one thread. You should create a new Transformer (typically by calling Templates.newTransformer()) for each transformation.